# Redirect to login page after logined to minio console

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, minio

I am going to run the service with Minio and I run it with docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    service_minio:
        image: quay.io/minio/minio:latest
        container_name: service_minio
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 9000:9000
            - 9001:9001
        volumes:
            - ./volumes/minio/data:/data
        environment:
            - MINIO_ROOT_USER=minioadmin
            - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=minioadmin
        command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
        networks:
            service_network:
                ipv4_address: 172.15.10.5
networks:
        service_network:
            external: true
```

And then i serve it with Nginx by below configuration:

```
server {
        listen 3000 default_server;
        listen [::]:3000 default_server;

        server_name mydomain.com;
        location / {
                access_log /var/log/nginx/minio_access.log;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/minio_error.log;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass http://172.15.10.5:9001;
        }
}
```

The problem is here, When i logged in to Minio Console, I will redirect to `/login` page without any errors. Actually i enter correctlly credentials but return back to `/login` page.

**Do you know where the problem is?**

Answer (score 0):

in most cases of configuring load balancer/proxy, `MINIO_SERVER_URL` needs to be set.
Please have a look at the documentation

[Environment Variable Documentation](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-server/minio-server.html#envvar.MINIO_SERVER_URL)

Comment: I set two below variables to **Minio** on `docker-compose` file but there is no changes.

MINIO_SERVER_URL=localhost:9000 MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL=localhost:9000 

@prakash-s